# CF API CF_SYNC_STATUS field in CF_OPERATION_INFO structure

Tags: windows, winapi, minifilter

In the Microsoft documentation [CF_OPERATION_INFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ns-cfapi-cf_operation_info) it is very briefly written that

> The current sync status of the platform.
>
> The platform queries this information upon any failed operations on a cloud file placeholder. If a
> structure is available, the platform will use the information provided to construct a more meaningful
> and actionable message to the user. The platform will keep this information on the file until the last
> handle on it goes away. If null, the platform will clear the previously set sync status, if there is one.

In other place of Microsoft [`CfReportSyncStatus` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfreportsyncstatus)  it is written that

> Once a sync status is located, the platform will use the information provided to construct a more meaningful and actionable message to the user.

I spent a lot of time trying to get this "a more meaningful and actionable message" from the system but without success.

In    `CloudMirror`    example I do the following.
Commented try part and leave only catch part, thus I believe that I am simulating a transmission error.

```
    void FileCopierWithProgress::CopyFromServerToClient(
        _In_ CONST CF_CALLBACK_INFO* lpCallbackInfo,
        _In_ CONST CF_CALLBACK_PARAMETERS* lpCallbackParameters,
        _In_ LPCWSTR serverFolder)
    {
        //try
        //{
        //    CopyFromServerToClientWorker(
        //        lpCallbackInfo,
        //        lpCallbackInfo->ProcessInfo,
        //        lpCallbackParameters->FetchData.RequiredFileOffset,
        //        lpCallbackParameters->FetchData.RequiredLength,
        //        lpCallbackParameters->FetchData.OptionalFileOffset,
        //        lpCallbackParameters->FetchData.OptionalLength,
        //        lpCallbackParameters->FetchData.Flags,
        //        lpCallbackInfo->PriorityHint,
        //        serverFolder);
        //}
        //catch (...)
        {
            TransferData(
                lpCallbackInfo->ConnectionKey,
                lpCallbackInfo->TransferKey,
                NULL,
                lpCallbackParameters->FetchData.RequiredFileOffset,
                lpCallbackParameters->FetchData.RequiredLength,
                STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL);
        }
    }
```

In the TransferData function I created the CF_SYNC_STATUS structure and put its address in the field opInfo.SyncStatus,
after that, CfExecute is called.

```
    LPVOID syncStatus()
    {
        std::wstring message(L"It is message to sync status");
        int lmessage = sizeof(message) + 2 +16;
        // round to 16
        int extra = lmessage % 16;
        lmessage -= extra;
    
        CF_SYNC_STATUS* ss = new CF_SYNC_STATUS{ 0 };
        ss->StructSize = sizeof(CF_SYNC_STATUS) + lmessage;
        ss->Code = 123;
        ss->DescriptionLength = lmessage;
        ss->DescriptionOffset = sizeof(CF_SYNC_STATUS);
        int size = sizeof(CF_SYNC_STATUS) + 16;
        BYTE* buffer = (BYTE*)malloc(size);
        memset(buffer, 0, size);
        memcpy(buffer, ss, ss->StructSize);
        wcscpy((wchar_t*)(buffer + sizeof(CF_SYNC_STATUS)), message.c_str());
        return buffer;
    }
    
    void FileCopierWithProgress::TransferData(
        _In_ CF_CONNECTION_KEY connectionKey,
        _In_ LARGE_INTEGER transferKey,
        _In_reads_bytes_opt_(length.QuadPart) LPCVOID transferData,
        _In_ LARGE_INTEGER startingOffset,
        _In_ LARGE_INTEGER length,
        _In_ NTSTATUS completionStatus)
    {
        CF_OPERATION_INFO opInfo = { 0 };
        CF_OPERATION_PARAMETERS opParams = { 0 };
    
        opInfo.StructSize = sizeof(opInfo);
        opInfo.Type = CF_OPERATION_TYPE_TRANSFER_DATA;
        opInfo.ConnectionKey = connectionKey;
        opInfo.TransferKey = transferKey;
    
        opInfo.SyncStatus = (CF_SYNC_STATUS*)syncStatus();
    
        opParams.ParamSize = CF_SIZE_OF_OP_PARAM(TransferData);
        opParams.TransferData.CompletionStatus = completionStatus;
        opParams.TransferData.Buffer = transferData;
        opParams.TransferData.Offset = startingOffset;
        opParams.TransferData.Length = length;
    
        winrt::check_hresult(CfExecute(&opInfo, &opParams));
    }
```

I do not see any difference between the case when the  opInfo.SyncStatus    field contains NULL and when it contains the address of the structure.

Does anyone know how to properly use this feature?

Thanks.

Comment: This feature is documented to be used when the sync provider is not running/connected and for failed operations only: "The platform will query this information upon any failed operations on a cloud file placeholder. Not sure what you expect it to do

Comment: @SimonMourier Indeed, about "upon any failed operations" we can read in documentation, but where do you read that "feature used when the sync provider is not running/connected"? When sync provider is not running I got "Make sure Provider is running on your PC, then try again" and it is quite expected. As to "what you expect" - I would like to see in some way the description that I am sending in the structure CF_SYNC_STATUS.

Comment: This is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfreportsyncstatus#remarks . Also note this SyncStatus structure is pretty recent and only for Windows 1803 or higher. I've never used it, but my guess is it's only to allow Windows to give end-user information for a failed op, when provider is not running. Maybe nothing uses it today. Explorer is just a hi-level user of the CFAPI and maybe doesn't support this yet. One thing for sure it's not needed to be able to use CFAPI, only optional.